# How to test a FastAPI endpoint that uses lifespan function?

Tags: python, testing, fastapi

Could someone tell me how I can test an endpoint that uses the new [lifespan](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/) feature from FastAPI?

I am trying to set up tests for my endpoints that use resources from the lifespan function, but the test failed since the dict I set up in the lifespan function is not passed to the TestClient as part of the FastAPI app.

My API looks as follows.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

ml_model = {}

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    predictor = Predictor(model_version)
    ml_model["predict"] = predictor.predict_from_features
    yield
    # Clean up the ML models and release the resources
    ml_model.clear()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/prediction/")
async def get_prediction(model_input: str):
    prediction = ml_model["predict"](model_input)
    return prediction
```

And the test code for the `/prediction` endpoint looks as follows:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_prediction():
    model_input= "test"
    response = client.get(f"/prediction/?model_input={model_input}")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The test failed with an error message saying
`KeyError: 'predict'`, which shows that the `ml_models` dict was not passed with the app object. I also tried using  `app.state.ml_models = {}`, but that didn't work either. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `TestClient` as a context manager. This triggers startup/shutdown events as well as lifespans.

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import app

def test_read_prediction():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        model_input= "test"
        response = client.get(f"/prediction/?model_input={model_input}")
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Here's some [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-events/) about testing startup/shutdown events. It also applies to lifespans.

Comment: Quality answer! Thanks a lot 

Answer (score -2):

Try importing lifespan instead of passing in `FASTApi` as you can give `startup` and `shutdown` in `testClient`

```
from app.main import app, lifespan

client = TestClient(app, startup=lifespan, shutdown=lifespan)
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you have appropriate FastAPI version. According to the [changelog](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/) lifespan is only available since [0.93.0](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/#0930).

If that doesn't help, try running uvicorn with [option](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#implementation) `--lifespan on`.